Is it natural to say "the news came to the king's ears"?
This phrase "there was a man who found a chest of gold. One day, the news came to the king's ears and the king decided to confiscate the chest" is translated from Vietnamese.
I guess you can predict the meaning of "the news came to the king's ears" (the king head of/about it).
Is it natural to say "the news came to the king's ears"?
If not, do we have a similar phrase?

It's completely normal.

It seems rather common in fairy tales, which retain certain formulas, but might be a bit out of place in everyday modern conversation. If one used it it might create a whimsical, fairy-tale-like tone. Much more common in modern use is "It has come to my attention," though it creates a very formal, stilted tone, as a passive replacement or euphemism for "I noticed" or "someone tipped me off."

More natural, I think, than "came to the king's ears" is "reached the king's ears".
FWIW, here's an ngram.

I was going to make exactly this comment.

Come to one's ears is found in thefreedictionary:

to be heard by one eventually

The idiom come to one's knowledge is more common and is defined as

to become known to one

Google has a similar phrase come to someone's knowledge:

become known to someone

The ears and knowledge versions
are all acceptable.
Ngram
The construction

the news came to the king's ears

is fine.
Edit2
The usage of a related version came to his ears is shown.
Please note there're duplicates.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=came+to+his+ears%2Ccame+to+his+knowledge&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3 one's is very formal. this NGrsm graph conforms more closely to typical usage. Note the rise in "came to his ears" since 2000.

Thanks, @JavaLatte.  I've borrowed your graphs and added to my answer.

I see this problem often with Ngrams. I looked at the strange upsurge in "came to his ears"; it would seem that it's suddenly and dramatically overtaken "came to his knowledge" in this century. But clicking through to the Google Books results, the first two pages of them are all reprints of works from past centuries (many of them the same one).

Thanks, @Andy Bonner.  I've edited my last paragraph.
